# Basic definitions

Tags: c#, class, object

Can you someone clearly define a class and an object with some practical examples?

Comment: They say, Google is our best buddy. I'm sure he has plenty of resources for this question ;-)

Comment: Yeah that's right Ajith but I couldn't get the clear definition. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Classes are a group of related methods and variables. Objects are instances of these classes.

Let's say you made a class dog that has the dog breed stored as a string

```
public class Dog
{
    public string breed;

    public Dog() //When no breed, makes breed unknown
    {
        breed = "unknown";
    }

    public Dog(string breedSet)
    {
        breed = breedSet;
    }
}
```

Now to make an object using the class Dog and the breed as Corgi

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog("Corgi");
```

And printing the breed of dog1

```
Console.WriteLine(dog1.breed);
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. Appreciate your help.